Rewrite the default RTE actions toolbar
Using Grapesjs to create a custom Ritch Text Editor, I want to completly rewrite the RTE Actions bar, to make it always visible in one of my panels.
The problem is that when I select a text range in the editable element and I click in my panel's button I loose text selection, si to fix this I'm doing a : editor.getSelected().trigger('active');
That way it works fine, but when I select another text in the same selection nothing happens.
Do you have some ideas please.
